# Hide file extension out of folders with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website is like organized like this:

- index.php
- products.php
- files

  - file_manager.php
  - another_file.php

I want to remove the extensions only from my files at root. So in this case, index.php should be index and products.php should be products but I don't want to touch on the file extensions inside folders. So file_manager.php and another_file.php should stay with the extensions

At this point my code is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php
```

but this code removes extensions from folders do.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak your regex to ensure that it affects root files only:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm.
Another thing, is it possible, when someone tries to access a file with extension, redirect to no extension?